# Order of Array Elements Causing Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays. Elements of each array are shown as below:

```
allLabBranches = [{
  "labbranchid": "1",
  "labname": "Wahab Labs, Islampura Branch, Lahore",
  "labtitle": "Wahab Labs Lahore",
  "shortname": "WAHB",
  "address": "56 Islampura, Lahore",
  "landlineno": "04237940445",
  "datecreated": "2016-03-11 11:00:00",
  "createdbyname": "Jamshaid Sabir",
  "createdbyuserid": "1",
  "dateupdated": "2016-05-04 00:53:03",
  "updatedbyname": "Jamshaid Sabir",
  "updatedbyuserid": "1",
  "clientgroups_clientgroupsid": "1",
  "startdate": "2016-05-04"
}, {
  "labbranchid": "2",
  "labname": "Wahab Labs, Model Town Branch, Lahore",
  "labtitle": "Wahab Labs Lahore",
  "shortname": "WAHAB",
  "address": "45 Model Town, Lahore",
  "landlineno": "04237945485",
  "datecreated": "2016-03-11 11:00:00",
  "createdbyname": "Jamshaid Sabir",
  "createdbyuserid": "1",
  "dateupdated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
  "updatedbyname": "",
  "updatedbyuserid": "",
  "clientgroups_clientgroupsid": "1",
  "startdate": "0000-00-00"
}, {
  "labbranchid": "3",
  "labname": "Shahdara More Branch",
  "labtitle": "Wahab Labs Lahore",
  "shortname": "WAHAB",
  "address": "Shahdara",
  "landlineno": "04237933415",
  "datecreated": "2016-03-11 11:48:15",
  "createdbyname": "Jamshaid Sabir",
  "createdbyuserid": "1",
  "dateupdated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
  "updatedbyname": "",
  "updatedbyuserid": "",
  "clientgroups_clientgroupsid": "1",
  "startdate": "0000-00-00"
}, {
  "labbranchid": "4",
  "labname": "New Branch",
  "labtitle": "Wahab Labs Lahore",
  "shortname": "WAHB",
  "address": "More Samanabad, Lahore",
  "landlineno": "042361561",
  "datecreated": "2016-03-11 11:52:06",
  "createdbyname": "Jamshaid Sabir",
  "createdbyuserid": "1",
  "dateupdated": "2016-03-14 15:06:44",
  "updatedbyname": "Jamshaid Sabir",
  "updatedbyuserid": "1",
  "clientgroups_clientgroupsid": "1",
  "startdate": "2016-03-14"
}, {
  "labbranchid": "5",
  "labname": "Test Branch",
  "labtitle": "xyz",
  "shortname": "sfwe",
  "address": "dsfasd",
  "landlineno": "sdfasd",
  "datecreated": "2016-03-12 00:14:11",
  "createdbyname": "Jamshaid Sabir",
  "createdbyuserid": "1",
  "dateupdated": "2016-08-11 12:54:12",
  "updatedbyname": "Jamshaid Sabir",
  "updatedbyuserid": "1",
  "clientgroups_clientgroupsid": "1",
  "startdate": "2016-03-12"
}, {
  "labbranchid": "6",
  "labname": "Test Branch 2",
  "labtitle": "asdfs",
  "shortname": "asdfs",
  "address": "asdf",
  "landlineno": "asdf",
  "datecreated": "2016-03-12 12:16:24",
  "createdbyname": "Jamshaid Sabir",
  "createdbyuserid": "1",
  "dateupdated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
  "updatedbyname": "",
  "updatedbyuserid": "",
  "clientgroups_clientgroupsid": "1",
  "startdate": "2016-03-12"
}, {
  "labbranchid": "7",
  "labname": "Wahab Labs, Shahdara Branch, Lahore",
  "labtitle": "Shahdara",
  "shortname": "Shahdara",
  "address": "Shahdara",
  "landlineno": "0423744915",
  "datecreated": "2016-08-11 12:56:27",
  "createdbyname": "Jamshaid Sabir",
  "createdbyuserid": "1",
  "dateupdated": "2016-08-11 12:57:01",
  "updatedbyname": "Jamshaid Sabir",
  "updatedbyuserid": "1",
  "clientgroups_clientgroupsid": "1",
  "startdate": "2016-08-01"
}]
```

Another array elements are:

```
labsOfUser = [{
  "userhasbranchid": "53",
  "labbranches_labbranchid": "6",
  "usersoflabs_userId": "9"
}, {
  "userhasbranchid": "54",
  "labbranches_labbranchid": "1",
  "usersoflabs_userId": "9"
}, {
  "userhasbranchid": "55",
  "labbranches_labbranchid": "7",
  "usersoflabs_userId": "9"
}, {
  "userhasbranchid": "56",
  "labbranches_labbranchid": "2",
  "usersoflabs_userId": "9"
}]
```

Now I have a Select Multiple Box and I show some branches as selected and some as not selected. The code is given below:

```
function populateSelectedLabs() {

    $('#labbranchids').empty();
    if (allLabBranches.length >= labsOfUser.length) {
      for (var i = 0; i < allLabBranches.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < labsOfUser.length; j++) {
          if (allLabBranches[i].labbranchid == labsOfUser[j].labbranches_labbranchid) {

            $("#labbranchids").append("<option selected='selected' value='" + allLabBranches[i].labbranchid + "'>" + allLabBranches[i].labname + "</option>");
            allLabBranches = jQuery.grep(allLabBranches, function(value) {
              return value != allLabBranches[i];
            });
          } //end inner if        

        } //end inner loop
      } //end outer loop
    } //end if
    for (var i = 0; i < allLabBranches.length; i++) {
      $("#labbranchids").append("<option  value='" + allLabBranches[i].labbranchid + "'>" + allLabBranches[i].labname + "</option>");
    } //end for loop


  } //end function
```

The problem is that array element comparison misses an element which is present in the array but located at different index in the array. The error occurs at following line of code:

```
if(allLabBranches[i].labbranchid == labsOfUser[j].labbranches_labbranchid){
```

Kindly help me to know how to compare all the elements in both array?

Comment: You're modifying `allLabBranches` inside the loop

Comment: Yes. I m removing those which are going to be shown as selected.

Comment: And by removing from the array inside the loop, you're messing up the count.

Comment: If order of elements of labsOfUser is ascending then it does not create any error.

Comment: That's generally true, if you do something like `for (var j = labsOfUser.length; j--; ) {...` you might avoid the issue

Answer (score 1):

The reason why certain items are not matched is that you redefine the `allLabBranches` inside the loop on that same array, making it shorter.

Let's assume that before that change the following is true:

```
labsOfUser[j-1].labbranches_labbranchid == allLabBranches[i+1].labbranchid
```

You would expect this equality to be detected later, in the next iteration of the outer loop. But because of the re-assignment to `allLabBranches`, this value no longer is at index `i+1`, but at `i`. This value will no longer be matched during the remaining part of the inner loop (because the matching value is at `j-1`), and so `i` will increment for the next iteration of the outer loop. As a consequence this value will never be matched.

You could solve this by iterating backwards through the `allLabBranches` array, but even better would be to create a hash with the values from the `labsOfUser` array. This will have better performance.

You can do that like this:

```
function populateSelectedLabs() {
    $('#labbranchids').empty();
    // create hash
    var hash = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < labsOfUser.length; j++) {
        hash[labsOfUser[j].labbranches_labbranchid] = 1;
    }
    allLabBranches = jQuery.grep(allLabBranches, function(value) {
        return hash[value.labbranchid];
    }).concat(jQuery.grep(allLabBranches, function(value) {
        return !hash[value.labbranchid];
    }));

    for (var i = 0; i < allLabBranches.length; i++) {
        $("#labbranchids").append($('<option>')
            .val(allLabBranches[i].labbranchid)
            .text(allLabBranches[i].labname)
            .attr('selected', hash[allLabBranches[i].labbranchid]));
    }
}
```

If the target browsers support ES6, then you could write it like this:

```
function populateSelectedLabs() {
    $('#labbranchids').empty();
    var hash = new Set(labsOfUser.map( value => value.labbranches_labbranchid ));
    allLabBranches.filter( value =>  hash.has(value.labbranchid) )
        .concat(allLabBranches.filter( value => !hash.has(value.labbranchid) ))
        .forEach( value =>
            $("#labbranchids").append($('<option>')
                .val(value.labbranchid)
                .text(value.labname)
                .attr('selected', hash.has(value.labbranchid)))
        );
}
```

Comment: The above code is not showing which labs are selected and which are not. You might have missed a line of code which appends the selected labs of the user. Thanks.